# Dialog Fragment not working with extended Fragment class but working with Extended Activity Class. Why?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I created class for picking up date using dialog fragment.

I want to use my dialog fragment here in this class (NOTE: this class extending fragment):

```
public class SingleShedulledTimeActivity extends Fragment
{ 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_single_schedule, container, false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }


    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) 
    {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        DialogFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        timePickerFragment.show(manager, "timePicker");
    }
}
```

Function showTimePickerDialog having a problem in this case (not recognizing getFragmentManager). But if I'm changing extended class from Fragment to Activity then there is no problem.

Can someone please explain why getFragmentManager is not working with Fragment class?

Comment: What do you mean by **"not recognizing getFragmentManager"**? Is this at build time or at run time?

Comment: Problem is in building time, ADT suggesting alternate as "Change type of manager to FragmentManager" If I'm doing that same suggestion I'm getting on the last line of that function.

Comment: Have you imported `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` or `android.app.FragmentManager`? If you are using the 'support' libs make sure that everything you import is from the `android.support.v4` packages.

Comment: Try using getActivity().getFragmentManager();